# JQuery onchange works multiple times in jsfiddle but only once in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, business-catalyst

I have added a jquery (1.11.1) script to a business catalyst site cart page to hide or display a message depending on what dropdown the user clicks. It works multiple times in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NathanHill/462tk/ but only once in my browser. The javascript is currently placed in line after the drop down.

I do not have control over the html dropdown so I cannot insert any function into the html onchange.

HTML:

```
<select onchange="SomeBCfunction(a,b,c);" id="shippingCountry">
    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="GB" selected="selected">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
</select>

<div id="zones">Show message</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#shippingCountry').on('change', function() {
            if ( this.value == 'GB')
            {
                $("#zones").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#zones").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to add/append to the existing BC function that is triggered Eg:

```
var SomeBCfunction = oldBCfunction 
Function SomeBCfunction (){ 
//my hide-display code 
oldBCfunction; 
}
```

but got nowhere with this...

Comment: Is the script added in the head?

Comment: First of all you remove this onchange="SomeBCfunction(a,b,c);" from tag. then try

Comment: Agree with @AnoopJoshi. Add $('#shippingCountry').removeAttr('onchange');
Before your new onchange.

Comment: I have no control over the onchange="SomeBCfunction(a,b,c); - it is generated by BC.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on chrome version 35.0.1916.153 m.

Ps. Removed the onchange="SomeBCfunction(a,b,c);" so the browser dosen't get and error each time you change the selected item, **but even with the onchange it works** multiple times, althougth if it is not used you should remove it.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class='required'>
    <select id="shippingCountry"> 
        <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
        <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
        <option value="GB" selected="selected">UNITED KINGDOM</option>   
    </select>
    <div id="zones">Show message</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('#shippingCountry').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'GB')
      {
        $("#zones").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#zones").hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I do not have control over the onchange written in the html. It is generated by business catalyst.

Comment: What browser are you testing?

Comment: So my guess is that the onchange function is changing something in the select or in the event propagation, dunno how you can solve it without access to that function.

Comment: Is there no way to add the display/hide script to the existing SomeBCfunction(a,b,c); without having access to this function?

Answer (score 0):

Not the finest way but did you try

```
$('#shippingCountry').on('click', function() {
```

And did you check, if any other script blocks or uses theese events?

Comment: I am not sure if this blocks or uses these events - I have very limited, if any access to the scripts that business catalyst use especially throughout the shopping cart process. Is there any way I can find out?

Comment: check all other included script on the site for a $('#shippingCountry').on('change', function() {

Comment: could you place a console.log('Debugging') in your script and check if the console ouput is only written once?

Comment: Sorry - I'm still new to javascript - you will have to be a bit more specific about what I steps I must perform with  the console.log

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#shippingCountry').on('change', function() {
          console.log("Debug"); //Add this here
            if ( this.value == 'GB')
            {
                $("#zones").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#zones").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Run your script, press F12 and open your console and watch how often there is a Debug.

Comment: This shows everytime I change a country in the console:

Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" 
AjaxPro.Request.invoke 
AjaxPro.AjaxClass.invoke 
Object.extend.Object.extend.ServerSideSetShippingCountry 
SetShippingCountry 
onchange

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to just create the function that BC writes to the HTML?

```
 function SomeBCfunction() {
     if $('#shippingCountry').val() == "GB" {
       $("#zones").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#zones").hide();
        }
      }
  }
```

Perhaps you could override the old function with a new one and include the action you need:

```
 var old_foo = foo;
     foo = function() {
      old_foo();
     bar();
  }
```

Comment: Not initally as I thought this would conflict with the real SomeBCfunctions Function - I just tested now and it does not work... Is there anyway I could monkey patch this?

Comment: So there is already s function by that name?  Wow, then you are creating conflicts and confusing JS.  Can we see what the BC created function looks like?

Comment: Yip - I have no access to that function so I cant even tell you what it looks like.

Comment: Can you do a page source extraction and then show us?

Comment: the SomeBCfunction is:    function SetShippingCountry(e,t,n){var r=document.getElementById("shippingPostcode");var i="";var s=document.getElementById("shippingState");var o="";var u=document.getElementById("catCartDetails");if(u){if(r)i=r.value;if(s){if(s.selectedIndex>0)o=s[s.selectedIndex].text}var a=CMS.OrderRetrievev2.ServerSideSetShippingCountry(t,e,o,i,n);u.innerHTML=a.value}}

Answer (score 0):

On each change, BC is discarding the entire content of `#catCartDetails`, including any event handlers you've attached.

You can prevent or hook into this by redefining the function `window.UpdateShipping()`, which is originally defined in `/CatalystScripts/Java_OnlineShopping.js`.

In your case, creating a function that's called after `ApplyDiscountCode()` should allow you to show `#zones` based on the value of `jQuery('#shippingCountry').find(":selected").text()`.

```js
window.UpdateShipping = function(e, t, n) {
  var r = document.getElementById("catCartDetails");
  if (r) {
    var i = CMS.OrderRetrievev2.ServerSideUpdateShipping(t, e, n);
    if (i.value[0]) {
      r.innerHTML = i.value[2];

      // Your logic here:
      checkShippingCountry();
    }
    if (i.value[1].length > 0) {
      if (/(iP[ao]d|iPhone).*?Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert(i.value[1])
        }, 0)
      } else {
        alert(i.value[1])
      }
    }
  }
};
```